# Select Element From List by Index with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<form id="foo">
    <input></input>
    <input></input>
    <input></input>
</form>
```

I want to do:

`document.getElementById("foo").getElementsByTag("input")[1];`

But in jQuery. I want to select a certain object under #foo by an index.

This is my first guess as to how to do this:

`$('#foo input[1]').val("BlahBlah");`

I think it would be the same in CSS too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
$('#foo input').eq(1).val("BlahBlah");
```

That will give you the second input. If you want the first, change the 1 to a 0. The `.eq()` function is 0 based.

Answer (score 3):

In jQuery there are a couple of methods defined to select and use elements from a (DOM objects) list.

By using:

```
var list = $("#foo");
```

You would capture the entire `#foo`. If your in for simplicity you could get the children (i.e  the input fields) by using `var children = list.children();` But if you want something that seems a bit more like findElementsByTag, you could use `var children = list.find('input');` (Which ofcourse could be a one liner, but usually you want to re-use the entire list too)

To get the first and last item of a certain list of children there are some predefined functions:

```
var first = children.first();
var last  = children.last();
```

To find an -nth element you can use http://api.jquery.com/eq/ or http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

So you would get (note it works just like an array with 0-based index)

```
var second = children.eq(1);
```

If you like CSS selector style more you can also try (note the 1-based index)

```
var second_b = $("#foo input:nth-child(2)");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#foo :input').eq(1).val('BlahBlah')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) selector:

```
$('#foo input:eq(1)').val("BlahBlah");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `eq` selector. It receives a zero-based index:

```
$('#foo input:eq(1)').val('a value');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use nth-child(n) pseudo class like this ...

```
$("#foo input:nth-child(0)").val("BlahBlah");
$("#foo input:nth-child(1)").val("BlahBlah");
.
.
.
$("#foo input:nth-child(n)").val("BlahBlah");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll say :

```
$($('#foo input')[1]).val("BlahBlah");
```